# Rate of change for the regression model $Y^{\frac{1}{2}}=a+b_1*log(X_1)+b_2*X_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: regression, model

Hello I have the regression model $Y^{\frac{1}{2}}=a+b_1*log(X_1)+b_2*X_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which works very well however I am trying to interpret it in terms of change for each different $X_i$ term. I know that the first derivative of $Y= a+b*X^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (which gives the rate of change) is:

$\frac{1}{2}*b*X^{-\frac{1}{2}}$; 
which is the same as:
$\frac{b}{2*X^{1/2}}$
so that's b divided by twice the square root of the independent variable. Since that's positive when $X$ is positive, $Y$ would increase as $X$ increases, but at a declining rate (this is the same pattern though not the exact same numbers as with the logged version of $X$

I have tried finding the first derivative of the original model but I get $b*\frac{1}{y^{1/2}}$ but then I get stuck.

What would be the rate of change for this model please ?

Comment: I have correctly typed your formulas. However they do not seem coherent, please check I have not made any mistake, and then if you have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood something in your question, you'd just use the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

$$Y^{\frac{1}{2}}=f(\mathbf{X})=a+b_1\log(X_1)+b_2\,X_2^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$Y=f(\mathbf{X})^2$$

$$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X_1}=2f.\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_1}=\frac{2b_1\,f(X)}{X_1}$$

$$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X_2}=2f.\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_2}=\frac{2f(X)\cdot b_2\cdot \frac{1}{2}}{X_2^\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{ b_2\, f(X) }{X_2^\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: That's great Glen thank you I really need to learn more calculus!  For the rate of change I also need to know if it's diminishing which from my understanding you can get from the second derivate, I think it's the second deriving test. Would you be able to help with that then I can piece together the econometric theroy. Thank you

Comment: But it's a function of two variables -- what's the actual condition you need to check? If you need only show it's decreasing with respect of each of $X_1$ and $X_2$ on its own, you can just divide those functions I gave through and see every term of each is decreasing in that variable. You can do that pretty much by inspection. However, do you also need to do something with the mixed second order derivative ($\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial X_1\partial X_2}$)??

Comment: Thank you once again for that explanation its very clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, nor that it is the correct place to post.
However, if you are only interested in the derivatives, I can maybe help you.

I see two ways of obtaining them :

1. Taking the square of your expression : $Y = (Y^{\frac{1}{2}})^2=(a+b_1*log(X_1)+b_2*X_2^{\frac{1}{2}} )^2 $  and then you should be able to derive.
2. Differentiate your expression

I will use the second

**For $X_1$**

$$\frac{1}{2}dYY^{-1/2}= b_1\frac{dX_1}{X_1}$$

so that

$$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X_1} = 2 b_1 \frac{\sqrt{Y}}{X_1} =2 b_1 \frac{a+b_1*log(X_1)+b_2*X_2^{\frac{1}{2}}}{X_1}  $$

**For $X_2$**

$$\frac{1}{2}dYY^{-1/2}= \frac{1}{2}b_2 dX_2 X_2^{-1/2}$$

so that

$$\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X_2} = \Big(\frac{X_2}{Y}\Big)^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{X_2}} \big(a+b_1*log(X_1)+b_2*X_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\big)  $$

Comment: Ok thanks for that maybe from that the in the case of x_1 x_2, b_1 and b_2 are positive so this will be positive so y will increase with x1 - probably at a diminishing rate but I would need the second derivate for that. The same is also true for x_2 as x_1, b_1 and b_2 are positive so this will be positive so y will increase with x_2 but again I would need the second derivative to confirm if it is diminishing.  Could you or someone help me with the second derivate please

Comment: Can't you do it by yourself ?

Comment: No not with stuff like this ie 2 X I can only do very simple calculus like in my first post.